# Cruiscontrol Force Build After Build Fails

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

buildafterfailed="true" does'nt work in .net, How can I do the same thing? I'm trying to have cruisecontrol triggers force builds until the build is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Project Trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger) with `triggerStatus` set to `Failure` and have a project monitor itself. buildafterfailed is specific to CruiseControl, from which CruiseControl.Net has diverged quite a lot.

As a side note - doing this either way is probably a bad idea.